# With mobile account enabled, is it safe to delete files from a computer that used to be used by someone else

Tags: macos, networking, mac, sync

I'm not very proficient with Macs and I'm not sure how the file syncing works across the network. Here's the scenario: I'm using a computer Bill Jole used to use. I noticed the hard drive is full and want to delete some unused files. The largest files are in `/Users/bill.joel/Wokspace/vms` can these be safely deleted even though he may need them on another computer?

Mobile account preferences are set to automatically sync at login and logout but only the home directory. The trouble is 1)I'm not sure what's included in the home directory 2)If it means everyone's home directory or only the currently logged in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't risk it and erase files or directories. I would get rid of his user profile. That way any syncing software would not notice any changes and just assume that the Mac was off the network.

Go to system preferences.

Select users & groups in 10.7 and later or Accounts in 10.6 and earlier.

You may need the admin password if the padlock in the bottom is locked.

Select Bill Joel in the list and hit the minus sign at the bottom.

It will give you options as to what you want to do with bill's files. I would find a place to back these up at least until Bill has a chance to verify that nothing went missing.

Comment: I don't think icloud has anything to do with this setup

Comment: noted and removed reference to it.

Comment: Thank you it worked! If you'd like to give more of an explanation, for example how mobile accounts work or the location of the home directory, feel free to.

Comment: macs have an intuitive file system. If you open a finder window and click on the "boot drive" often called macintosh hd under devices you will see the shared resources Applications, Library, and System. Then in Users you will see a Shared folder. This is to share files with other users on that computer, not over a network. You should also see your user name. This is your home directory. This is where your files are kept.